# Stored Procedure using data from different table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have stored procedure. How I can call this procedure taking data from different table.  idGroup is column name from different table.

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `simpleproc`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`sa`@`192.168.1.253` PROCEDURE `simpleproc`(IN idGroup INT, IN groupName varchar(20),IN beginDate date, IN weekday1 INT, IN weekday2 INT, IN lessonCount INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE i int;
DECLARE name1 int;
DECLARE price int;

SET  i:=1;
WHILE i<=lessonCount  DO
  SET beginDate:=DATE_ADD(beginDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  IF WEEKDAY(beginDate) in(weekday1,weekday2) THEN
    SET name1:=groupName+i; 
    SET price:=price DIV 8;
    insert into lessons (lessonName, idGroup, lessonPrice, datePassed) 
      values (name1,idGroup,price,begindate);
  END IF;
  SET i:=i+1;
END WHILE;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Syntex to call is:
`CALL simpleproc(1, 'abc', '2015-10-10 12:12:43', 2, 3, 4);`

Comment: If you want to iterate the value based on some table values then you can write a stored procedure which will be having a cursor to select and fetch those values in some variable, based on your conditions you can call above stored procedure with   `CALL simpleproc(1, 'abc', '2015-10-10 12:12:43', 2, 3, 4);`